# Make PhpStorm add a warning if calling a function with more arguments than declared

Tags: phpstorm

Using PhpStorm 8.0.3.
Let's say I have this function:

```
public function myFunction($argA, $argB) {
    // ...
}
```

And I'm calling it from somewhere else in the project with one extra argument, like:

```
$myClass->myFunction($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

I know this **is not** considered an error in PHP, and it can be useful in some scenarios... but it **is** wrong according to my own *coding standards*, so I just wanted to know if there's a way to make PhpStorm to warn me if I'm doing it somewhere...

Comment: PhpStorm version used?

Comment: @LazyOne sorry, it's 8.0.3 - updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do anything about it in PhpStorm v8.0.3.

But PhpStorm v9 already has [separate inspection](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6008) for that. If you want -- [try v9 EAP build now](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program).

Comment: Thanks! looking forward to v9